# Story/novel about an alien world that achieves spaceflight in its solar system by engineering organic vegetable matter that operates as a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, books, space

In the 1960s or '70s I read a story/novel featuring a world that achieved space flight by engineering biological (vegetative) material. Does anybody know what it might be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you can recall any other details about this story/novel, please [edit] your question to add them in.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did this world interact with humans at all?  Did they meet other alien races?

Comment: They're both 1980s Instead of 60s-70s, but you might contrast Bob Shaw's [*Land and Overland*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_and_Overland) series and Brunner's [*The Crucible of Time*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/872586.The_Crucible_of_Time).  The former features humans who build wooden spaceships, the latter aliens who grow them.  If you can identify how the story you're looking for differs from them it would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you David W. I certainly read a lot of Brunnerand so that may be it. I’ll take a look. I’ll get back to you. Also, my recollection is that they did not interact with Terran humans.

Comment: David W. Thank you, the crucible of time is definitely it. I have mentioned this plot aspect to my son for 15 years and I’m pretty sure he believes I imagined it on some acid trip. But who needs acid when you have John Bruner. Thanks again. (As Benny Noakes used to say, “ christ what imagination I have got“

Comment: Side note: Larry Niven's "[Known Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known_Space)" universe contains "stage trees." They are living trees that were genetically engineered by an ancient, long-dead, spacefaring civilization. The ancients are presumed to have harvested the mature trees and used their trunks as solid-fuel rocket motors. The "feral" trees found on many planets, if left alone long enough, eventually ignite and take off on their own.